# After changing my appcompat and targetSdk to 23 Spinners Dropdown became dark on v2.3 Android

Tags: android

I have recently updated the targetSdkVersion and appcompat of my app to v23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow) after this update evertyhing works fine except on Android 2.3 Gingerbread the spinner are not shoing the contents on dialog insted it is showing in dark drop down background where the items are not visible.

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Color_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/Color_700</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

spinner

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/replayspin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Replay_prompt"
            android:entries="@array/Replay_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/Replay_prompt"/>
```

Sample image on Android 2.3 Gingerbread

[image]

Comment: try to create custom spinner and give required properties to your dropdown.

Comment: If i create a custom spinner it will affect android version above 2.3 which is working fine now.

Comment: I already said to give all required properties to your dropdown. Believe me your changes will be visible across all versions.  Few days back I had same problem.

Comment: i had same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661614/spinner-black-text-color-in-dark-theme-appcompat-v23

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it turned out in my case that it was because I was using one of the android.layout.xxx layouts in my ArrayAdapter:

`adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

If that's what you are doing then try creating a new layout in your project and copy in the layout provided with the Android SDK, in my case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

You'll then need to change the style attribute to be `style="?spinnerDropDownItemStyle"` - which uses `spinnerDropDownItemStyle` as set in the appcompat theme, not `android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle`.

You'll also need to change the layout_height because `?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight` is not visible.  I used `android:layout_height="?dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"`.