# Spinner black text color in dark theme AppCompat v23

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-support-library, android-appcompat

My theme extends from **Theme.AppCompat** but the text color is black like the background

with the light theme works perfect

this problem is only in API 10 (2.3.6) with above version works perfect.

i use a **AppCompatSpinner** and my activity extends from **AppCompatActivity**

[image: Spinner Wrong color]